# Error when installing packages in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, package

While trying to install packages in R, I'm getting the following error. How to overcome it?

```
install.packages("rgdal")
Installing package into ‘/home/bibin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgdal_1.0-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1631619 bytes (1.6 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++
configure: rgdal: 1.0-4
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... no
configure: svn revision: 548
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/home/bibin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp7d3VjY/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Hint: `configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.` Type `gdal-config` in a terminal to see which Linux package to install.

Comment: You want `libgdal-dev` or similar. As Pascal says

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I installed libgdal-dev, and tried to rgdal package in R again, but now it's showing the following error.

configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.

Comment: You need to install proj4 Linux library too: `libproj-dev`.  Please **read** the _SystemRequirements_ [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) next time.